# Java InvocationHandler and a Singleton

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a singleton object "MySingle" which all through my classes I retrevie as `MySingle.createOrGetInstance();`

Now the problem I am having is that I would like to do some Method Logging and other stuff before a method in MySingle is called, so I looked into the Java InvocationHandler class [Source Link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html)

However the problem is now how would I call the singleton method, because when I use the same code and instead of doing

```
DebugProxy.newInstance(new FooImpl());
```

I do this

`DebugProxy.newInstance(MySingle.createOrGetInstance());` But when I do this, I get a class Cast expression when I end up assigning the result to a variable `(MySingle sing).

Im developing on Android but I doubt that makes any difference :).

Thanks,
Faisal abid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normal java application (I don't know android) it will fail, because the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` will only work for interfaces!

> A dynamic proxy class (simply referred to as a proxy class below) is a class that implements a list of interfaces specified at runtime when the class is created, with behavior as described below.

@see: [Proxy Java Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

In your case, the DebugProxy from the java reflection guid (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html), uses java.lang.reflect.Proxy!

In your code `MySingle` is a class, but a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` only implement the Interfaces of this class. So casting a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, created for the class `MySingle`, to the **class** must `MySingle` fail with an class cast exception, because the Proxy is not an subclass of `MySingle`.

One workarround that would work: would be intoducing an Interface MySingle and implemement a class MySingleImpl (with the getInstance method), and then use everywhere (except creation) the interface.

Answer (score 0):

For android application debug is diff. calss which is implemented for specially for android

---

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html)